# How to format! a pat(enum) in rust macro_rules

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I have a problem when I use `macro_rules!`.

I defined a `enum Test` and impl `fmt` for the enum.

```rust
 use core::fmt;
    #[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Eq)]
    pub enum Test {
        Foo(String),
        Bar,
    }
    impl fmt::Display for Test {
        fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
            match self {
                Test::Foo(id) => write!(f, "Foo({})", id),
                Test::Bar => write!(f, "Bar"),
            }
        }
    }
```

Then I defined a macro `print_test!`.

```rust
macro_rules! print_test {
    ($test:pat) => {
        println!("the Test is {}", $test);
    };
}
```

However I got an error .

```rust
error: expected expression, found `Bar`
  --> src/main.rs:53:36
   |
53 |         println!("the Test is {}", $test);
   |                                    ^^^^^ expected expression
...
57 |     print_test!(Bar);
   |     ----------------- in this macro invocation
```

I'm a new Rustacean. And I really don't know why this happened.

---

#### update

I have already import the enum variants in a global scope.And  following is the complete code

```rust
mod test {
    use core::fmt;
    #[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Eq)]
    pub enum Test {
        Foo(String),
        Bar,
    }
    impl fmt::Display for Test {
        fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
            match self {
                Test::Foo(id) => write!(f, "Foo({})", id),
                Test::Bar => write!(f, "Bar"),
            }
        }
    }
}
use test::Test::*;
macro_rules! print_test {
    ($test:pat) => {
        println!("the Test is {}", $test);
    };
}
fn main() {
    let a=String::from ("test");
    print_test!(Bar);
}
```

Comment: Enum variants are not in a global scope by default. Try `Foo::Bar` instead or `use Test::*` and then `Bar`. I am pretty sure this is a duplicate, but can not yet find one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you import and reference enum types in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21323812/how-do-you-import-and-reference-enum-types-in-rust)

Comment: Sorry for that I forgot the post the complete code.I have imported the enum variants in  a global scope. And if I change `$test` to `Bar`,the code can run without any error.

Answer (score 2):

Just change the `pat` to `expr` can resolve the problem.

```rust
macro_rules! print_test {
    ($test:expr) => {
        println!("{}",$test);
    };
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you're using either `pat` or `path`: in your expansion, `$test` is just an expression / value (an RHS). `pat` is a *pattern* (an LHS, either target of an assignment or pattern of a match arm) and `path` is a qname. Why aren't you declaring `$test` as `expr`? [Then it works fine](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=96881c72d022f53206a26d573f45d93c).

Comment: Also it's super not convenient that you only post bits and bobs and readers have to try and reconstitute what's supposed to surround it. Posting an entire test case (reduced to the bare minimum showing the issue), ideally alongside a playground link, is pretty useful to reader.

Comment: Thanks,`expr` works for me.This is my first time ask a question in stackoverflow(>~<),and I will do my best to learn the art of how to ask a question.Thanks again for your solutions.

Comment: okay!The problem has be solved .I will change the answer. Thanks for your remind.